# How to find empty table column, including `th` and inject data into it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Updated [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/XCfAQ/32/):

How would you find an empty table column,including `th` in the fiddle so that when you click on a button it'll inject data into that column only. For example, when you click on "X" it'll add data to the first empty column,"G" will add data to the second empty....When the table is full, start from the second child column (because the first column is some sort of title column) and replace old data in that column.

Just a guess:

```
columnTh = $("table th");
columnIndex = columnTh.index() + 1; 
columnIndex.each(function(){
if ($(this).html() == '' && $('table tr td:nth-child(' + columnIndex + ')').html() == ''){
     // add data
}
```

But how can I check if the whole table is full so that the button will add data to the first column again?

HTML:

```
<div class="area">
    <select>
        <option>Choose</option>
        <option>R</option>
        <option>T</option>
    </select>
    <div class="show">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="area">
    <select>
        <option>Choose</option>
        <option>X</option>
        <option>G</option>
    </select>
    <div class="show">
    </div>
</div>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Placeholder</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Race</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nationality</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Education</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Language</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS Code

```
$(function (){
  $('.area').each(function(){
   var area = $(this),
       selectbox = area.find('select'),
       show = area.find('.show'),   
       dialog_open =  $(this).find(".dialog_open");


   selectbox.change(function(){
    selectbox = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    show.html('<button class="dialog_open">'+selectbox+'</button>')
    });

   var foo = function() {
   var dialog_open_text = $(this).find(".dialog_open").text();
      $('table td').html(dialog_open_text);  // ****Need help in this part*****
   };

   show.one( "click",dialog_open, foo );

  });

});
```

Comment: By empty, do you mean every cell in that column has no data?

Comment: @user3558931, yes, I'm trying to find the whole column including `th` `td` is empty, in order to add data one column at a time.

Comment: Do you want to fill the table column by column or the whole table as in your demo. How do you decide which column number you're filling?

Comment: @user3558931 I want the buttons to fill the table column starting from the leftest empty column, it doesn't have to fill data based on the column number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to check that the table is full:

```
var allCells = $('table').find('th,td').length;
var fullCells = $('table').find('th,td').filter(function() { 
    return $(this).text() != ''; 
}).length;

if( allCells === fullCells ) { // if true table is full, not full otherwise
    //do something table is full
} else {
    //table is not full
}
```

If the first select indicates the column # you're targeting and the second select indicates the content to put in the cells of the column, then you may use the following logic inside the function foo:

```
var colN = $('select').first().val(),
    colCont = $('select').last().val(),
    allColumns = $('table').find('th:eq(' + (colN - 1) + '),td:eq(' + (colN - 1) + ')').length,
    fullColumns = $('table').find('th:eq(' + (colN - 1) + '),td:eq(' + (colN - 1) + ')').filter(function() { return $(this).text() != ''; }).length;
```

Then you can check to see if the targeted column is full or not:

```
if( allColumns === fullColumns ) { 
    //all cells in target column full
} else {
    //not all cells in target column are full
}
```

You can empty everything but the first column this way:

```
$('table').find('th,td').not(':first-child').empty();
```

And here's how to fill a column:

```
$('td').filter(':nth-child(' + colN + ')').html(dialog_open_text);
```

Comment: It gives me some idea. Thank you. I'm thinking about, if the table is full, using `.empty()` to empty all the table columns except the first-child column (because it's a title column (Age, Description), if you know what I'm talking about, then start adding data again from the leftest empty column.

Comment: Now you have me confused. The first column is not (Age, Description) ... etc. That's actually the first row. Did you mean to speak about rows the whole time or this is a new requirement? If so since the titles are in a `th` element then you would just empty `td` elements only.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I used the firebug to make sure I get the selectors right. I was talking about emptying everying except all of the `tr td:first-child` and the `th:first-child` when the table is full.

Comment: I've simplified and reworked the code a little. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XCfAQ/56/) I can only add a class to the next empty column but when I use `html`, it doesn't display the text. Still a long way to go.

Comment: I wish I knew what your goal was. I would provide better help. See [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XCfAQ/57/).

Comment: I appreciate your help. It's close. Basically I'm trying to set up a  comparison table and a few buttons that represent some information. When someone clicks the buttons, the table will show their respective information in a column dynamically on click. It is similar to **this [link](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-add-rows.html)**, but instead of adding extra row, I just want to add data into the existing columns

Comment: Great! If you have any further questions, do not hesitate to let us know.